# Why menu-close Attribute Clear History Page?

Tags: ionic-framework

I do not understand why `menu-close` cleared the cache, for this reason I can't back to the previous page.

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item  class="item-icon-left" menu-close ui-sref="app.home">
        <h2 class="menu-text">home</h2>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item  class="item-icon-left" menu-close ui-sref="app.org">
        <h2 class="menu-text">org</h2>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item  class="item-icon-left" menu-close ui-sref="app.groups">
        <h2 class="menu-text">group</h2>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: What is your problem actually? As you can see in the related `menu-close` code the `nextViewOptions` is set to `historyRoot = true` [see Github](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/js/angular/directive/menuClose.js#L46). This clears your history cache...

Comment: when I use ´menu-close´ BackButton in next page doesn't appear, and when to write a function to close the menu and use ´$ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleRight();´ its work a BackButton it's appear!.

Answer (score -1):

This post from the Ionic team could contains your solution:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/any-way-to-not-reset-history-stack-on-menu-close/16340

As you say, using the menu-close tag, clear the history. For this reason, if you want to keep the history, you should avoid the use of menu-close and try to build your own action instead to close the menu.

Something like adding a ng-click to each item of your menu:

```
 <ion-item ng-click="closeMenu()" ui-sref="page2">Page 2</ion-item>
```

And then build your own action-click (in this example closeMenu()). This method just gonna contains the piece of code to tell your app what to do/how to close the menu (since the piece of code contains nothing about the history, the history gonna be preserved).

```
$scope.closeMenu = function() {
     $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
}

$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
    disableAnimate: true
});
```

And of course don't forget to delete the menu-close attribute from your html ;)

Tried this solution today to enhance my app, it worked like a charm. Thx to brandyshea from the Ionic team for the nice solution documented in the linked post.